# Not able to Received the id in onKeydown in react

Tags: reactjs

code:-

```
   useEffect(() => {
        setPlayer();
        window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
        return function cleanup() {
            window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
        };
    }, [props])

  const handleKeyDown = (event, ID) => {
        if (event.key === "Delete") {
            //alert(name);
            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: `${API_ENDPOINT}/api/setCue?Idx=${ID}&RDL=${props.val}`,
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Access-control-allow-origin': '*'
                },
                auth: {
                    username: 'admin',
                    password: 'password'
                },

            }).then(response => {
                console.log("Delete Inside Axios");
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log("Error In Post Data", error);
            });
            console.log("Delete Key Press", ID, props.val);

        }
}



 <tbody>
                   
        {
       PlaylistData && PlaylistData.map((playdata) => {
     return (
          <tr key={playdata.idx} tabIndex={playdata.idx} className="border_bottom"
        KeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, playdata.idx)} onLoad={() => active(playdata.idx)}                              
                 >
         <td style={{ color: "white", width: "200px" }}>
            <img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64}`} alt="Clip Thumbnail" width="50%" />
                                    </td>
```

when I click the delete button it does not send the table index but when I remove the window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown); its sending the id number but not the props values
I want both id and props values to print in the console.
How can I fix that?
please help.

Comment: Where is that `ID` coming from? keydown event handler should have only one argument, the event.

Comment: ID from API. I am  trying, when the user presses the delete btn it tells the backend which row id and value will delete from the backend

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of target using `event.code == "Delete"`. So replace `event.key` by `event.code`

You can see the example below to see how it works i.e. go to input and then press any key to see the key entered.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const log = document.getElementById('log');

input.onkeydown = logKey;

function logKey(e) {
  log.textContent += ` ${e.code}, `;
}
```

```html
<input>
<h3 id="log"></h3>
```